# Android application using html

Tags: android, windows, web

When you say android application I understand its a .apk executable. But When you say developing android application using html, does it mean we still get a .apk file or when we develop using html, is it then called as android web development, which means you won't get a .apk file. But you get a html file that runs on android browser. Is that a correct statement. Because apart from Java and C# Xamarin which will produce a .apk file, I dont think html--->.apk file never happens.
So .apk file means apps similar to windows applications, and using html means we
 create a mobile web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it mean we still get a .apk file or when we develop using html

It can, if you are using tools like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).

> or when we develop using html, is it then called as android web development, which means you won't get a .apk file

An HTML5 Web app, particularly with offline caching, can feel a bit like an app. However, it would be written as a Web site or Web app and distributed as such, not distributed in the form of an APK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So any HTML development will have apps running in browser and may be if I use phone gap I can convert the html app ---> apk and execute it standalone with out browser? Is that a correct statement?

Comment: @SARAVAN: Yes, that is the basic idea.